# Jasper report for nested objects

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jasper-reports

I have to generate a single PDF report which should have the below objects - 
User : this object has 5 fields

```
1. id : integer
2. fname : string
3. lname : string
4. email : string
5. address : this is of type Address,
```

the Address object has 3 fields.

```
1. id : integer
2. city : string
3. type : string
```

In the pdf report i need below columns -

```
Id(from user class) Name Email City Type
```

I am able to get the User object fields but not sure how to get the Address object fields. 
Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<field name="Id" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[userId]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="First_Name" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[fname]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="Last_Name" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lname]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="Email" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[email]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="City" class="com.demojasper.model.Address">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[city]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="Type" class="com.demojasper.model.Address">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[type]]></fieldDescription>
</field>

<pageHeader>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="5" width="380"
                height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#777765" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font reportFont="Arial" />
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Report 1"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="15" backcolor="#CBB453" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font reportFont="Arial" />
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="60" y="0" width="100" height="15" backcolor="#CBB453" />
            <textElement>
                <font reportFont="Arial" />
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[First Name]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="170" y="0" width="100" height="15" backcolor="#CBB453" />
            <textElement>
                <font reportFont="Arial" />
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Last Name]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="280" y="0" width="100" height="15" backcolor="#CBB453" />
            <textElement>
                <font reportFont="Arial" />
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Email]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="390" y="0" width="100" height="15" backcolor="#CBB453" />
            <textElement>
                <font reportFont="Arial" />
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[City]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="500" y="0" width="100" height="15" backcolor="#CBB453" />
            <textElement>
                <font reportFont="Arial" />
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[City Type]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="30">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" />
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer">
                <![CDATA[$F{Id}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="100" height="20" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" />
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[$F{First_Name}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="170" y="0" width="100" height="20" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" />
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[$F{Last_Name}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="100" height="20" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" />
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
                <![CDATA[$F{Email}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="390" y="0" width="100" height="20" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" />
            <textFieldExpression class="com.demojasper.model.Address">
                <![CDATA[$F{City}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="100" height="20" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" />
            <textFieldExpression class="com.demojasper.model.Address">
                <![CDATA[$F{Type}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

User class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_INFO")
public class User 

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int userId;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String email;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private Collection<Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>();
```

Address class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_ADDRESS")
public class Address 

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int addrId;
private String type;
private String city;
```

Comment: thanks for correction @Alex K . Can you help with my request or share some link which could help. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: it's java, you have the object Address, create and then call methods as `$F{Type}.getCity()`